# Docker nginx as reverse proxy to other docker compose projects

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

So I just started working with docker. I have some goal in my mind, and I'm not even sure if it's possible. So I wanna dockerize everything. I am currently working on Win 11 (WSL2) and Docker Desktop.

My goal is to make docker-compose.yml for system, and others per project.

So it's like I wanna have nginx, certbot, mongodb and redis system-wide.
For this, I currently have this config:

```
version: "3.5"
name: system
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./volumes/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/:ro
      - ./volumes/certbot/www/:/var/www/certbot/:ro
      - ./volumes/certbot/conf/:/etc/nginx/ssl/:ro
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - system-network
  certbot:
    container_name: certbot
    image: certbot/certbot
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/certbot/www/:/var/www/certbot/:rw
      - ./volumes/certbot/conf/:/etc/letsencrypt/:rw
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/mongodb/data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - system-network
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/redis:/data
    networks:
      - system-network

networks:
  system-network:
    name: system-network
    driver: bridge
```

This is currently working, and I can access everything in it (nginx, mongodb etc...)

Now I have 1 NextJS project, that needs to connect to that mongodb. Inside root of that project, I have "docker" folder, and inside it I have "development" and "production" folders. Current docker/development/docker-compose.yml for that project is:

```
version: '3'
name: hein-cms
services:
  hein-cms:
    container_name: next-app
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: docker/development/Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ../../.env
    volumes:
      - ../../src:/app/src
      - ../../public:/app/public
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - system-network

networks:
  system-network:
    external: true
```

Now my question is, how do I reference mongodb container from 1st docker-compose inside this second (or any other project)?

By the way, I also have defined a domain inside "volumes/nginx/conf.d/test.example.com". Now the other problem is, how do I define proxy_pass there as well, because "localhost:3000" isn't working.

Is there any solution for this, or is my approach wrong?